# The JButton is not responding, why?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to make button show a message when pressed, it's not working. Can anyone tell me what I missed?

In the end I have the `KeyListener` and the if for `JOptionPane`, but the website is not letting me post it (I'm new to this).

Anyway, it would be really nice if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, thanks.

```
public javalearning(){

FlowLayout f = new FlowLayout();
setLayout(f);
this.setSize(200,200);

JFrame j = new JFrame();
this.setTitle("this is a tittle");

JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText("Button");
    this.add(button);

    JButton button2 = new JButton();
    button2.setText("Button2");
    this.add(button2);

    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Where's the listener?

Comment: There's no code for the button to do anything. Here's an idea: check out the tutorials on how to use JButtons, such as [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), the first hit from a Google search `java jbuttton tutorial`.

Comment: as i said in the post, i have the listener but this website is not letting me post it

Comment: The site will let you post any text and code you need to post, as long as it's not a ton of code (which you don't want to post anyway). If you're trying to post an image with code in it, don't. Only post code as text that can then be formatted as code.

Comment: You want to show a message when the button is pressed, what kind of 'message' do you mean?
An output with `System.out.println()` or a `JLabel` with the message?

Comment: The site lets you enter code if you put it in a code block. Otherwise it may tell you something like "this code should be in a code block". Paste your code, select it with your mouse, and use the button with `{}` on it to make it a code block.

Comment: *"In the end I have the `KeyListener`.."*  A `JButton` works better with an `ActionListener` since the latter will respond to both keyboard **and** mouse input.  OTOH (it seems) that is not the immediate problem.  BTW - Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> In the end I have the KeyListener and the if for JOptionPane,

As the [tutorial that I've linked to in my comment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) will explain, you don't use KeyListeners with JButtons but rather ActionListeners.

e.g.,

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       System.out.println("Button pressed");
   }
});
```

---

You state:

> but the website is not letting me post it (I'm new to this).

This site will let you post any reasonable amount of code. If you're having problems posting it, tell us the specifics of what's wrong, and maybe we can help you. Again, if you're trying to post code as an image, don't. It should be text that is formatted as code, not an image. But most important, don't keep us in the dark, or we can't help you.

Answer (score 2):

please follow example in this code and you will be fine. If at the end of the day you are unable to resolve it. you can write back. i believe this will help you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ChangeButtonLabel{
  JButton button;
  public static void main(String[] args){
  ChangeButtonLabel cl = new ChangeButtonLabel();
  }



  public ChangeButtonLabel(){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("This is a Frame");
  button = new JButton("Button");
  button.addActionListener(new MyAction());
  frame.add(button);
  frame.setSize(400, 400);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public class MyAction implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  String text = (String)e.getActionCommand();
  if (text.equals("Button2")){
  button.setText("I am Sectona");
  }
  else{
  button.setText("Click Me");
  }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: it finally worked, thanks. But just out of curiosity, is there an alternative to ''if (text.equals(button))''? i mean another statement to make a button responsive, isn't there a statement like in javascript with OnClick or something like that? thanks again.

Comment: @Javanoob: you still should improve your original question as none of us are yet clear on what your current (or even past) problem is.

Comment: haha actually i dont really know, umm im really new to java, even though im loving this language, its really hard to understand some of the statements. im trying to make it simple by asking dumb questions haha. anyways. the thing was just to make a program with 2 buttons that show a message when you press them so now that's accomplished, so what im doing next is i want to put a few pictures in the program, and use the 2 buttons as next and back to show the pictures

Comment: @Javanoob: OK, so you've got your ActionListeners working now? In the future, you will want to show your ActionListener code, or any code that is critical to your question, with your question. As for swapping images, the easiest way to do that is to place your images into ImageIcons, perhaps placing them into an `ArrayList<ImageIcon`, add a JLabel to your GUI and then swap the icons that the label displays via its `setIcon(...)` method.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

like Hovercraft said, you will need to set ImagIcon(String image_name)

The code below will help you in embedding image on JButton. Give me a shout if you still find it difficult to integrate

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class IconButton{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Icon on button");
  JButton button = new JButton("Image button fro Sectona");
  Icon imgicon = new ImageIcon("sectona.gif");
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  button.setIcon(imgicon);
  panel.add(button);
  frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  frame.setSize(400, 400);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```